# unable to bind the image slider jquery to the click function

Tags: jquery, slider

I want the script to be called on the click of anchor tag as the script is running after the page loads.If i write it on click function.  This gives the error as "`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`"

Refrence to that slider is 
http://www.basic-slider.com/

```
<script class="secret-source">
                        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {                        
                            jQuery('#jquerySliderClick').click(function ($) {
                                debugger;
                                $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
                                    animtype: 'slide',
                                    height: 160,
                                    width: 1000,
                                    responsive: true,
                                    randomstart: true
                                });
                            });
                        });
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi~ i'm trying to help you but i can't speak english well.. ^^;
mm.. i changed your scoure...
but i couldn't find target by click(id="jquerySliderClick")
check your code again

```
<div id="myModel4" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog mdal-wdh-Slider">
            <div class="modal-content" style="border: 3px solid #428BCA; top: 150px" id="mc1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">
                        <div class="hdng-4 center">Announcements</div>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                
                    <div id="banner-slide" style="width:100%;">
                        <ul class="bjqs">
                            <li>Hi All This is the first slider</li>                      
                            <li>Hi All This is the Second slider</li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <script class="secret-source">
                            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                                jQuery('#jquerySliderClick').click(function($){
                                    $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
                                    animtype: 'slide',
                                    height: 160,
                                    width: 1000,
                                    responsive: true,
                                    randomstart: true
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chknotification" name="notification" style="margin-top:-2px;" />
                        <span style="padding-left:11px;">Dont Show me notification on next visit.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center"> 
                        <input type="submit" value="Close" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-primary blu-bt" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```